# Show with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ that the function $f(x) = \frac{2x+3}{5}$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Show with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ that the function $$f(x) =
> \frac{2x+3}{5}$$ is continuous.

I found this task on the internet but it was without solution, so I'm asking here if I did it correctly.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and let $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. If $|x-x_{0}|< \delta$, then:

$$\left |\frac{2x+3}{5} - \left(\frac{2x_{0}+3}{5}\right)\right | = \left|\frac{2x+3-(2x_{0}+3)}{5}\right|=\left|\frac{2x+3-2x_{0}-3}{5}\right|$$

$$=\left|\frac{2x-2x_{0}}{5}\right|<|2x-2x_{0}|=\left|2(x-x_{0})\right|<|2\delta|=\varepsilon$$

Therefor, the function is continuous.

---

Is it alright?

I'm not sure because I have just removed $5$ from the denominator and claimed it's greater without (it really is..). But am I actually allowed to do that?

Comment: Your proof is correct

Comment: your proof is correct only because of you remove 5from denominator

Comment: Since yo have modulus you can able to remove 5

Comment: Alternatively you can keep the 5 and let $\delta=5\varepsilon/2$.

Comment: @Olivier Moschetta I don't agree

Comment: I think he is right that would be another way of solving it. But I'm not sure too, that's why I asked :D

Comment: You need to show for the chosen $\delta$,|f(x)-f(a)|must be strictly <$\epsilon$@cnmesr

Comment: If u choose$\delta=5\epsilon/2$then you have equasl sign not <

Comment: @SathasivamK, if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ (as claimed) you still have strict inequality.

Comment: @cnmesr, removing 5 from the denominator makes the denominator smaller.  If you divide by a smaller number, the result is greater.

Comment: @TravisJ,i'm sorry for that comment, i just forget about it. thank

Comment: Guys I don't get it... Is my proof correct or wrong?

Comment: Your proof is just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Your proof is complete. Are you doubting that whenever $A < B$ and $B < C$, then also $A < C$ ? Don't :)

Comment: could not comment this. This was more like a comment